# C# Using Listbox to display only a select few characters of description

Tags: c#

The code i currently have below populates a list box with the Id, description and company

```
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dTable);

            DataColumn dcDisplayMember = new DataColumn("DisplayMember");
            dcDisplayMember.Expression = string.Format("{0}+'\t\t'+{1}+'\t\t'+{2}", "dId", "Description", "Company");


            dTable.Columns.Add(dcDisplayMember);


            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = dTable;
            listBox.DataSource = bSource;
            listBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
```

However what i am trying to achieve is getting the list box to display a shorter version of the description column e.g. description of something...

I know i have to do something to

```
string.Format("{0}+'\t\t'+{1}+'\t\t'+{2}", "dId", "Description", "Company")
```

But i am not sure as to what

Comment: Are you saying that the `Description` may be N characters long and you only want to display up to the first M characters, where M is less than N?

Comment: I think you can use another list, then iterate through your datatable and select certain few characters from the description and add into that list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please try using SUBSTRING for description. like this one ..   string.Format("{0}+'\t\t'+{1}+'\t\t'+{2}", "dId", "SUBSTRING(Description, start, length)", "Company")

For example you want first 10 chars then try passing like this
string.Format("{0}+'\t\t'+{1}+'\t\t'+{2}", "dId", "SUBSTRING(Description, 0, 10)", "Company")

If this solves your problem please let me know i will add this as answer.